# how implement clock widget with onclicklistner?

Tags: android, android-widget

I am implementing clock widget in that it have one button when i click on button it will open another Activity that activity have one edit text, i enter some data in that edit text. that text will appear on widget. but my problem is the activity is not open when click on button.